# Android. Не работает Service

Tags: java, android

Создал Service, чтобы в фоновом режиме связывался с "DropBox"

Так объявил в AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service
        android:name=".DownloadDropboxService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
</service>
```

Так запускаю Service в методе onCreate:

```
startService(new Intent(this, DownloadDropboxService.class)); //Запускаем сервис
```

Вот код самого сервиса:

```
public class DownloadDropboxService extends Service
{
    private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN = "xxxx ... xxxx";

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public static void main(String args[]) throws DbxException 
    {
        // Create Dropbox client
        DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("dropbox/java-tutorial", "en_US");
        DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2(config, ACCESS_TOKEN);
        // Get current account info
        FullAccount account = client.users().getCurrentAccount();
        System.out.println(account.getName().getDisplayName());

        Log.d("TAG_LOG", "DownloadDropboxService запустился"); 
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Понимаю, что не запускается, так как в логах нет надписи "DownloadDropboxService запустился", которую я прописал `Log.d("TAG_LOG", "DownloadDropboxService запустился");`

Answer (score 0):

В андроиде метод `main` не используется вообще. Приложение и его структурные составляющие запускаются системой после обработки `Intent`-ов. В случае сервиса будет вызван метод `onCreate` при создании оного и `onStartCommand` при каждом запуске `Intent`-а сервиса.

В зависимости от того, как вам надо вам надо перенести весь код из `main` метода в `onCreate` или `onStartCommand`, переопределив нужный.